Space prison colony riot with just two survivors
I remember watching a sci-fi film which was set in space.  It featured an all female crew who were sent to a prison colony to rescue the last surviving guard (I think there had been a riot).  Upon arrival, the crew found that there were two people still alive, one identified as a guard and one identified as a prisoner.  Both of them claimed to be the guard.  One by one the crew were killed.  
I think the film was called something along the lines of 'Prisoner XXXX' (the four X's being his number).
